# Structure of Stock Management System

Tags: c#, .net

In my current program structure when a product is sold it loops through a list of products, I'm making no use of my inventory class.

My intention is when a product is sold it will loop through my current inventory find that item and do the appropriate functionality - i.e. update quantity to inventory, but I'm not quite sure how to use my inventory class with my ProductManagement class. Hopefully this somewhat makes sense, thanks :)

```
 class Product
{
    public int _id;
    public int _price;
    public int _quantity;

    public Product(int id, int price, int quantity)
    {
        _id = id;
        _price = price;
        _quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

---

```
class Inventory
{
    private List<Product> _products = new List<Product>();

    public Inventory(List<Product> products)
    {
        _products = products;
    }
}
```

---

```
class ProductManagement : IProduct
{

    public List<Product> inventory = new List<Product>();

    public void addProduct(Product product)
    {
        inventory.Add(product);
    }

    public void productSold(Product product)
    {
        inventory.Remove(product);
        foreach(Product p in inventory)
        {
            if(p._id == product._id)
            {
                p._quantity = p._quantity - 1;
            }
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Rather than using inventory in ProductManagement as a list of Products, I feel as though my actual inventory class should be referenced here instead, somehow? @Dai

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See if this is what you are looking for:

```
class ProductManagement : IProduct
{
    public Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
    public void addProduct(Product product)
    {
        inventory.AddProduct(product);
    }

    public void productSold(Product product)
    {
        //TODO: consider accepting quantitySold as a parameter, as you could sell more than 1 quantity of the same product
        var quantitySold = 1;
        inventory.UpdateProduct(product._id, quantitySold);
    }

}

class Inventory
{
    private List<Product> _products = new List<Product>();

    public Inventory()
    {

    }

    public void AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        //TODO: add checks if product already exists
        _products.Add(product);
    }

    public void UpdateProduct(int id, int quantity)
    {
        //TODO: check if id is valid
        var product = _products.Single(x => x._id == id);
        product._quantity -= quantity;
    }
}
```

I would recommend going through C# Coding Conventions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions

Comment: you aren't online to answer a question by any chance :P ? @matt.G

Comment: go ahead..what is your question?